# imprimir as linhas de acordo com o array

Tags: php, array

Como imprimir esse meu array dessa forma:

> NOME|TELEFONE|EMAIL|DATA DE NASCIMENTO FAVORITO|DESCRCAO

Só consigo imprimir por colunas

segue o código

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<?php session_start(); ?>
<html lang="pt-br">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Lista de Contatos</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form>
            <fieldset>
                <legend>Lista de Contatos</legend>
                Nome<br>
                <input type="text" name="nome">
                <br>
                Telefone<br>
                <input type="tel" name="telefone">
                <br>
                Email<br>
                <input type="email" name="email">
                <br>
                Data de nascimento<br>
                <input type="date" name="dataNascimento">
                <br>
                Favorito <input type="checkbox" name="vip" value="Favorito">
                <br>
                Descrição<br>
                <textarea name="descricao" rows="10" cols="30">
                </textarea>
                <br>
                <input type="submit" value="Cadastrar">
            </fieldset>
        </form>
        <?php
            if(isset($_GET['nome'])){
                $_SESSION['l1'][] = $_GET['nome'];
            }
            if(isset($_GET['telefone'])){
                $_SESSION['l1'][] = $_GET['telefone'];
            }
            if(isset($_GET['email'])){
                $_SESSION['l1'][] = $_GET['email'];
            }
            if(isset($_GET['dataNascimento'])){
                $_SESSION['l1'][] = $_GET['dataNascimento'];
            }
            if(isset($_GET['vip'])){
                $_SESSION['l1'][] = $_GET['vip'];
            }
            if(isset($_GET['descricao'])){
                $_SESSION['l1'][] = $_GET['descricao'];
            }


            if(isset($_SESSION['l1'])){
                $lista_contatos = array();
                $lista_contatos = $_SESSION['l1'];
                ?>
                <table border="1">
                    <tr>
                        <th colspan="6">Contatos Cadastrados</th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Nome</td>
                        <td>Telefone</td>
                        <td>Email</td>
                        <td>Data de Nascimento</td>
                        <td>Favorito</td>
                        <td>Descrição</td>
                    </tr>


                        <?php foreach($lista_contatos as $contatos) : ?>
                            <tr>
                                <td><?php echo $contatos; ?></td>

                        <?php endforeach?>


                </table>
        <?php } ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Se você quer imprimi-los nessa sequência, por que não usa a função `implode`?

Se entendi que você quer imprimir os índices, e não os valores, faça da seguinte forma:

```
echo implode('|', array_keys($lista_contatos));
```

Essa função é responsável por "unir" os elementos de um `array`, para transformá-los numa única `string`.

Por sua vez, `array_keys`, retornará um `array` com todos os `indices` utilizados no seu `$lista_contatos`.

Answer (score -1):

```
$contato = array();
if(isset($_GET['nome'])){
  $contato['nome'] = $_GET['nome'];
}
if(isset($_GET['email'])){
  $contato['email'] = $_GET['email'];
}
...

$_SESSION['l1'][] = $contato; 

...
<?php foreach($lista_contatos as $contato) : ?>
    <tr>                            
        <td><?php echo $contato['nome']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $contato['telefone']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $contato['email']; ?></td>
        ....
    </tr>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: Não entendi sua resposta, só tem código?